# Get language for Calender folder 0365

Tags: azure, powershell, office365

This is the request from a user:

User wants to have viewing access to all the calendars of all the employees.
I found a powershell script to do this
`Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity user1@company.com:\Calendar -User user2@company.com -AccessRights Reviewer`

This works fine for people who have their language set to English.
But because i work in Belgium we have 3 official languages (dutch, french and german). Management decided user get to choose their language.
This means my script only works for the english language and other it throws an error.

So i need to find a way to find out which language they have configured so i can run the right command based on this.
English = `:\Calendar`
Dutch = `:\Agenda`
French = `:\Calendrier`
German = `:\(no idea, did not yet encounter it)`

Comment: I don't have an Exchange org to test against, but I suspect you should be able to discover any calendar folder owned by a given mailbox with something like `Get-MailboxFolder -Identity user@company.tld |Where-Object FolderClass -like Calendar*`

Comment: @toto i had the same problem i solved it by building if statement with dutch agenda  $mbox = $mTextBox1.Text + ":\Agenda"
        $resultaat = Get-MailboxFolderPermission -identity $mbox | Select FolderName, user, AccessRights  $mbox = $mTextBox1.Text + ":\calendar" 
        $resultaat = Get-MailboxFolderPermission -identity $mbox | Select FolderName, user, AccessRights

Answer (score 0):

```
    $resultaat = write-host $mTextBox1.Text
try {
         
    $mbox = $mTextBox1.Text + ":\calendar" 
    $resultaat = Get-MailboxFolderPermission -identity $mbox | Select FolderName, user, AccessRights -ErrorAction stop
    Write-Host  "Is a Calendar"

}
catch {
    $mbox = $mTextBox1.Text + ":\Agenda"
    $resultaat = Get-MailboxFolderPermission -identity $mbox | Select FolderName, user, AccessRights
    Write-Host "Nederlandse  Agenda"
           
}
```

Comment: yeah this is what I thought of as well. But what if the calendar is in French? 
I have three (with german four) languages to check. A try catch inside another try cath inside another is not very clean

Comment: @Toto for the French you can google it   (you need to use if else for the items  ,,,,,)

Comment: for French it is :\Calendrier. 

But on which parameter do i base my if else statement? 

´´´´if ($language -eq ENG) 
{ then use :\Calendar ...}
else if ($language -eq FR) 
{ then use :\Calendrier ...}
else 
{ then use :\Agenda } ````

Comment: ````if ($language -eq ENG) { then use :\Calendar ...} else if ($language -eq FR) { then use :\Calendrier ...} else { then use :\Agenda }````

Answer (score 0):

It was not the first time for me that I had this problem and I always somehow worked around it like you did with the try and catch or nested if statements but I wanted to find a solution now once and for all and I came up with this. Maybe someone finds this helpful.

```
# Initialize $UserEmail Variable with the user's email
$UserEmail = "Useremail@domain.com"

# Grab all the user's calendars
$UserMailboxFolder = Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics -Identity $UserEmail -Folderscope Calendar

# Concatenate the user's email and the FolderPath of the first calendar object
# which always seems to be the primary calendar which also makes sense because
# that calendar always exists when creating a new mailbox (and we flip the slash)
$UserPrimaryCalendar = "$($UserEmail):$($UserMailboxFolder[0].FolderPath)".Replace("/","\")
```

Now that we have the full path to the user's primary calendar we can e.g. get the permissions of that calendar like so and save them in a variable

```
$UserPrimaryCalendarPermissions = Get-EXOMailboxFolderPermission -Identity $UserPrimaryCalendar
```